# How to evaluate $\int\frac{(\cos2x)^2}{(\sin2x)^{3/2}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus

How would you evaluate $\displaystyle\int\frac{(\cos2x)^2}{(\sin2x)^{3/2}}\,dx$?

Comment: [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+cos^2%282x%29%2Fsin%282x%29^%283%2F2%29) gives a very strange answer.

Comment: Please excuse this question as it is somewhat off-topic. How do you produce mathematical symbols on these pages like for example the integral?

Comment: @JulesManson: Something called latex is used. for example, one can form an integral with an $\int_{y}^{x}$ command. I would google latex math symbols. This will give you a list of commands.

Comment: @JulesManson: [Guide to MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), or see the help center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int\frac{\cos^22x}{\sqrt{\sin^32x}}dx=\frac12\int\frac{\cos^2t}{\sqrt{\sin^3t}}dt=-\int\cos t\cdot d\bigg(\frac1{\sqrt{\sin t}}\bigg)=-\frac{\cos t}{\sqrt{\sin t}}-\int\sqrt{\sin t}\,dt,$$ at which point we have to recognize the expression of the [incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind) in the latter term.

Comment: Lucian you are a gentleman and a scholar. I thank you sir.